# Ошибка загрузки этого URI: Could not load the source for http://localhost/

Tags: php, localhost, uri

Пытаюсь довести до рабочего состояния скрипт на пхп. **Тестирую на локалхосте** (xampp). И вижу в консоли такую ошибку в отладчике:

> **Ошибка загрузки этого URI: Could not load the source for http://localhost/my_test/script1-1.php.**

И сейчас туда же добавилось еще:

> Ошибка карты кода: TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch
>   resource. URL ресурса:
>   moz-extension://2a5c365a-01e2-785c-abff-2017f3de8c2f/node_modules/webextension-polyfill/dist/browser-polyfill.js
>   URL карты кода: browser-polyfill.js.map[Подробнее]

Скрипт (php cURL) должен зайти на целевой сайт, авторизоваться и получить данные.
И, вот, такую ошибку получаю.

Моих знаний не хватает понять, что это значит. Я с пхп пока "на Вы". Первый скрипт мучаю. Предполагаю, что на сайте закрыт доступ с локалхоста?

Буду благодарна за подсказку, что это такое и как его победить.

P.S. Вот еще, что нашла по этому поводу (перевод от яндекс. переводчик):
Это, вероятно, проблема брандмауэра. Curl по умолчанию пытается использовать порт 1080, который, вероятно, не открыт на вашем localhost / router / ISP.

Добавила xampp в исключения брандмауэра, но ничего не поменялось к сожалению.
Порт 80 используется httpf.exe, то есть локальным сервером.

Как решить проблему? 
Спасибо!

Comment: В какой консоле ошибка? какой код выдает эту ошибку? Причем тут вообще огнелис с его расширениями и какое отношение это имеет к вашим скриптам?

Comment: В консоли браузера (firefox). Ошибку выдает код скрипта, запускаемого в браузере на локалхосте. Причем тут файерфокс. кроме того, что это его консоль, я тоже не знаю, блин. Скрипт мучаю свой второй в жизни (первый нормально домучила). Поэтому и спрашиваю,что это и как это исправить? И про отладку php-кода в консоли браузера - это не я придумала. https :// web-finder.ru/otladka-php-koda-v-konsoli-brauzera - например, тут почитайте, только пробелы уберите. Я только начала (причем, по необходимости) в пхп разбираться. Если абсурд, - извините уж. Если есть, что подсказать, буду рада.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как оказалось, в консоль браузера выводилась ошибка, связанная с утилитой cURL. Для ее включения и нормальной работы потребовалось

**1. в файле php.ini раскомментировать строку extension = php_curl.dll

2. скопировать файлы ssleay32.dll, libeay32.dll из папки php 
в папку C:WindowsSystem32
3.перезагрузить windows.**

После этого ошибка (Ошибка загрузки этого URI...) пропала. В самом браузере стали нормально выводиться ошибки php.

Может, кому-нибудь пригодится